# Full width to the ion cards under the ion-content

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, ionic3

I need to give a full width to the ion card. This works:

```
ion-card{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100% !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
      }
```

But I need to restrict it only to the children of `ion-content`. So tried this. But it is not working. i.e. It removes the full width of the cards. Any clue?

```
 ion-content>ion-card{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100% !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
      }
```

*html*

```
<ion-header>
 <ion-card>
      <h2>Notifications Area1</h2>
  </ion-card>
</ion-header>

    <ion-content>
      <ion-card>
        <h2>Notifications Area2</h2>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-content>
```

**Note:** I don't need to apply full width to the `ion-header` card.

Comment: The child 100% width is the 100% of the parent, if the parent won't have 100% so does its children.

Comment: Oh.. Sorry, I didn't get what you told. can you give a code example how can I do this? @ItayGal

Comment: What do you mean by "removes the full width of the cards" it not respecting container element width?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dew0cLxq/ you were close, just replace the `>` with a blankspace  and it works

Comment: Please see the update @Hanif

Comment: Please adjust this according to my latest update @RamondeVries

Comment: Yes, your solution works. Can you put that as an answer and any explanation why `>` is not working? @RamondeVries

Comment: @Sampath http://jsfiddle.net/dew0cLxq/1/ this is changed abit, i left the width on all cards. my bad

Comment: Please put that as an answer. Then I can accept it @RamondeVries

Comment: @Sampath But why do I have to remove `>`? http://jsfiddle.net/dew0cLxq/2/ I don't understand the problem here... sorry :\

Comment: I think maybe you're not using the ionic framework on your example no. With ionic and on the device `>` is not working. @ReSedano

Comment: @Sampath ah ok! That's good to know. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be your solution: remove the `>` and change it for a `blank space`.

Here's some explaination on why to use the `blank space`,

> element element,  `<div>` `<p>` Selects all `<p>` elements inside `<div>` elements,
>
> element>element   `<div>` `>` `<p>`   Selects all `<p>` elements where the parent is a `<div>` element

and in your case, the blankspace works better.

```css
ion-card{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin: 0 !important;
        background: blue;
        width: 500px;
      }
ion-content{
  background: green;
}
ion-content ion-card{
  background: yellow!important;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ion-content>
  <ion-card>
    <h2 text-center margin-top>Notifications Area</h2>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>

<ion-card>
    <h2 text-center margin-top>Notifications Area</h2>
  </ion-card>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've amended the formatting on the HTML and the CSS a bit.

HTML

```
<div class="ion-content">
  <div class="ion-card">
   <h2 class="text-center margin-top">Notifications Area</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ion-content {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   width: 100%;
   background: grey;
   height: 500px;
}



.ion-card {
    flex-basis: 100%;
}

h2 {
   color: blue;  
}
```

You can see a working example here. https://codepen.io/Angel-SG/pen/aPpWVM

Answer (score 0):

```
ion-content {

    ion-card {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100% !important;
        max-widht : 100% !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
    }
}
```

try this I hope it should work...!